# How to play iPhone music from within Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina, apple-music

iTunes was replaced with the *Music* application in Catalina.

I can no longer find the option to play music from my phone. Am I overlooking something or was this feature removed entirely?

From the Catalina *Music application*: Is it possible to play iPhone audio files through the lightning connection?

Comment: iTunes still exists in Mojave. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Tetsujin Crap! Meant to say Catalina.

Comment: Hokay ;-) I can't help on Catalina, sorry, don't have a Mac in the building can run it :\

Comment: All good. I wouldn't rush to it. That's for sure.

Comment: I share this question, and would clarify that in Music on Catalina I can see the songs on my iPhone, but cannot play any of them (play button is non-responsive in Music). Not sure if this is intentional.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear but if you want to use your iPhone as an audio input and play music from iPhone using the speaker of MBP then do the following steps:

Before following the instructions, make sure you’ve got a Lightning USB cable handy (the same one you use to charge your device). You’ll need it to complete the setup process. When you’re ready, follow the step-by-step guide below:

1. Connect your iPhone to your computer using the USB cable.
2. On your Mac, open Audio Midi Setup. You’ll find it in **Applications** > **Utilities**.
3. If you don’t see your iPhone listed in the left-hand panel, go to **Window** > **Show iOS Device Browser.**
4. Locate your iPhone in the list of devices and highlight it.
5. Click on Enable. Your phone will now appear as an input device.

No further steps are required. Any audio you play on your phone (again, except phone calls) will be reproduced on your Mac.

[image]

However, to justify my answer (if it doesn't suit your question), iTunes still exists in Mojave. You can sync all your music and can clearly play everything from MBP directly.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say Catalina.

Comment: I should also mention that I usually played music in iTunes itself. Not through speakers.

Comment: I can enable the iPhone as an input and see the Input Level responding to sounds on the System Preferences -> Sound window, but can not for the life of me figure out how you would pipe that straight to the display speakers. Running on Catalina.

Comment: I've made a workaround hack: After following the steps above to enable your iPhone as a MIDI input, you can open GarageBand and add your iPhone as an Audio input. Check the "I want to hear my instrument as I play and record" and you will be able to listen to your iPhone's songs on your Macbook or Display speakers! If this gets voted up, I will transform it into an answer, building on @Udhy's answer.

Comment: *Sigh* GarageBand also isn't a good fix, as it creates opportunities for feedback or skipping when your computer is under heavy load. I am used to being able to play my personal music collection over my work speakers, and really miss this on Catalina.